# How to store lines from a text in a file into an array and print the lines at desired locations in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, printing

How can I store lines from a text into an array and then print specific lines at desired locations? In my coi.txt file, there are 15 lines. I actually wanted to pull those lines from the text and print it at the specif location that I have mentioned in the code. It is a kind of iteration. Please help. Thank You. I am really sorry for the messy code, but I am just a beginner. Here is my code:

```
    package todo;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Repeat 
    {
        public void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
                        
            String[] SENTENCE;
        final Scanner sentence = new Scanner(new File("coi.txt"));
        final ArrayList<String> sentenceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        while (sentence.hasNextLine())
        {
            sentenceList.add(sentence.nextLine());
        }
    
        sentence.close();
    
        final String[] sentenceArray = sentenceList.toArray(new String[sentenceList.size()]);
    
        for (int r=0;r<sentenceArray.length;r++)
        {
            SENTENCE = sentenceArray[r].split("(?<=[.!?])\\s*");
            for (int k=0;k<SENTENCE.length;k++)
            {
                int n1, n2, n3;
    char a,b,c;
    n1 = 59;
    n2 = 40;
    n3 = 41;
    a = (char) n1;
    b = (char) n2;
    c = (char) n3;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    
    for (int j = 0; j<=10; j++) {
    System.out.println("art = new Part"+b+c+a);
    System.out.println("art.setTitle"+b+"\""+"Article "+ j +"\""+c+a);
    System.out.println("art.setDescription"+b+"\""+SENTENCE[k]+"\""+c+a);
    System.out.println("art.setDetail"+b+"\""+"\""+c+a);
    System.out.println("art.setId"+b+"\""+"partV"+"\""+c+a);
    System.out.println("articles.add"+b+"art"+c+a+ "\n");
            }
    
        }
            }
```

### **DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
art = new Part();
art.setTitle("");
art.setDescription($$"NEED TO PRINT THE SPECIFIC LINES FROM THE ARRAY HERE"$$);
art.setDetail("");
art.setId("part");
articles.add(art);
```

Comment: Please share more details.. Also, full code whatever you have tried till now.

Comment: Are you saying that you have those 6 lines in a file and you want to print them?

Comment: @Scratte, actually that is the output I desire. the lines in the text file are different. I want specific lines to be printed inside: 

`art.setDescription($$"NEED TO PRINT THE SPECIFIC LINES FROM THE ARRAY HERE"$$);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ArrayList` have been used instead of an array. Then the list is turned back to an array. This part is for reading the lines from the text and storing them in the ArrayList.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/text"));
String str;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
    list.add(str);
}

String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

And for accessing specific lines:
e.g for printing line 6

```
art.setDescription(stringArr[5]);
```